# Is this paper written in a good manner?

Tags: publications, mathematics

I searched the Internet to find an open-access article about cubic equation solving methods.

I have found [this one](http://www.nickalls.org/dick/papers/maths/cubic1993.pdf) which has good information I've never met before. Also, the original paper is [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3619777) by the same author; but it should be reached from University IP.

But the problem is that I think It is not written in the way an article should be.

For example, look at this sentence from the paper:

> In addition to their value in curve tracing, I have found that the parameters , ℎ,
>  and , greatly clarify the standard method for solving the cubic since unlike
> the Cardan approach

Which is written in an **active** tense rather than passive. We ignore it that there is also a typo here and in other parts of the paper: "Cardan instead of Cardano".

Also, the author of the paper is in fact, an [anesthesizer](http://www.nickalls.org/dick/index.html) at Nottingham University Hospital; so mathematics isn't his field at al.

I have found an article in anesthesia by him too and the active tense can be again seen there.

Is this article or author really of academic writing?

Comment: You should really focus on whether the information is correct.  There may be differences in academic writing across different fields.  Also, an author may not be trained in academic writing.

Comment: *there is also a typo here and in other parts of the paper: "Cardan instead of Cardano".* [...] *so mathematics isn't his field at al.* --- Surely you did this to see if anyone would notice? Regarding active and passive voice, keep in mind that the journal *Mathematical Gazette* (in which I've published two articles, by the way) is a journal for **mathematical exposition**, and often active voice makes for better exposition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no rule that says that papers have to be written in passive voice. In fact, [Nature's style guide](https://www.nature.com/nature-research/for-authors/write) says

> Nature journals prefer authors to write in the active voice ("we performed the experiment...") as experience has shown that readers find concepts and results to be conveyed more clearly if written directly.

Most of the papers I have read were not written in passive voice.